# In XSL: How to avoid choose-blocks for wrapping elements?

Tags: xml, xslt

there is a case, that appears often times. I am parsing an XML and generate my XHTML document via XSLT 1.0.

Case:

```
/* XML */
<Image src="path-to-img.jpg" href="link-to-page.html" />

/* XSL */
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@href">
    <a href="{@href}">
       <img src="{@src}"/>
    </a>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <img src="{@src}"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

You see the problem: I am just fetching the case if there is a href set. I'm not satisfied with this approach, but I don't see another option for implementing this.

Any ideas?

Comment: could you explain more verbosely what's wrong with this approach?

Comment: it has redundant code. the img-element is same in both cases. the only difference is the wrapping a-element. - i need to know if you can wrap with elements in a more elegant way. futhermore it is not maintainable, because you have to change (in this case) everything twice.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple and short(est) solution that has no explicit conditional instructions. :)

Comment: Also added an XSLT 2.0 solution that uses the new XSLT 2.0 instruction `<xsl:next-match>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The way to eliminate explicit conditional instructions inside a template is to use pattern-matching within the match pattern of a template**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="Image[@href]">
    <a href="{@href}">
     <xsl:call-template name="basicImage" />
    </a>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Image" name="basicImage">
   <img src="{@src}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 2.0:** There is an especially ellegant solution using **[`<xsl:next-match>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#element-next-match)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="Image[@href]">
    <a href="{@href}">
    <xsl:next-match/>
    </a>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Image" name="basicImage">
   <img src="{@src}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Both transformations, when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Image src="path-to-img.jpg" href="link-to-page.html" />
```

**produce the wanted, correct result**:

```
<a href="link-to-page.html">
   <img src="path-to-img.jpg"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Option #1 you can create non-conditional `a` and image bellow  and using `xsl:if` append  attribute (note in this case there is some lack - always exists tag `a` but without href - for end user it is not a problem):

```
<a>
   <xsl:if test="@href">
      <xsl:attribute name="href" value="{@href}"/>
   </xsl:if>
   <img src="{@src}"/>

</a>
```

Option #2 If javascript is applicable - just place to img handling of `onclick`

Answer (score 2):

To avoid duplication of code, you could make use of named templates, to contain the code for rendering the **img** tag

```
<xsl:template name="img">
   <img src="{@src}" />
</xsl:template>
```

You can then call it like so

```
<xsl:call-template name="img" />
```

So, the finished XSLT would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/Image ">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="@href">
            <a href="{@href}">
               <xsl:call-template name="img" />
            </a>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="img" />
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="img">
      <img src="{@src}" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Although you still have two **xsl:call-template** commands, any changes to the rendering of the **img** tag now only have to be done in one place. You could also call this template from anywhere within your XSLT, assuming the current node is an **image** node.