# How to conditionally output tags?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Tags can be outputted by either directly typing

```
  <div>
    <span>complex...</span>
  </div>
```

or using `<xsl:element>`,

```
  <xsl:element name="div">
    <span>complex...</span>
  </xsl:element>
```

My question is how to do this: **when x, output `<div>`, when y, output `<a>`, when z, output no tag**?

One of course can make three templates, or even write ugly code as

```
<xsl:when ...x >
    <![CDATA[ <div>  ]]> 
</xsl:when>

<span>complex...</span>

<xsl:when ...x >
    <![CDATA[ </div>  ]]> 
</xsl:when>
```

but is there a way to conditionally provide the value of the name attribute of xsl:element?

I tried this, failed:

```
<xsl:variable name="a" select="'div'"/>
<xsl:element name="$a">
...
```

[edited] Forgot to say, XSLT1.0 only

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201423/in-xsl-how-to-avoid-choose-blocks-for-wrapping-elements

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to look at it:

```
<xsl:variable name="content">
    <span>complex...</span>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when ... x>
        <div>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$content"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when ... y>
        <a>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$content"/>
        </a>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when ... z>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$content"/>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `name` attribute is not expecting a full-fledge XPath expression but simply a string. So, instead of using `name="$a"` you only have to evaluate the Xpath expression into a string by bracing it with curly braces:

```
<xsl:element name="{$a}">
```

As for the conditional creation of the surrounding tag you could do something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="tag_name">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="x">
      <xsl:text>div</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="y">
      <xsl:text>a</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>

  <!-- possibly other checks for different tag names -->

<xsl:variable>

<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$tag_name != ''">
     <xsl:element name="$tag_name">

       <!-- whatever has to be put into a tagged block (A) -->

     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:when>

  <xsl:otherwise>

     <!-- whatever has to be put into a untagged block (B) -->

  </xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>
```

If `A` and `B` are equal you could put that into a template.

Comment: Good for "when x, output `<div>`, when y, output `<a>`".  Do you know how to do "when z, output no tag"?

Comment: See my updated answer. Another, probably more elegant, way to handle this would be using match templates with different modes. Would you you be interested in that? It may result in more profound changes of your overall XSLT though, if you're not using match templates so far.

Comment: @MarcusRickert Can you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69207608/xslt-masking-data-conditional-on-other-tags

Answer (score 0):

XSLT doesn't output tags: it outputs nodes to a result tree. Your suggestion of using constructs like `<![CDATA[ </div>  ]]>` is therefore way off the mark: you can't add half a node to a tree.

However, there's no difficulty with conditional generation of elements nodes. If you want to create an element but compute its name conditionally, then in XSLT 2.0 you can do

```
<xsl:element name="{if (test) then 'a' else 'b'}">
```

or if you're stuck with 1.0, the much more verbose

```
<xsl:variable name="elname">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="test">a</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>b</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:element name="{$elname}"/>
```

If you want to output an element or nothing depending on a condition, just do

```
<xsl:if test="test2">
  <e/>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: How to output an element or nothing conditionally which wraps something else as in `<span>complex...</span>`?

Comment: The contents of xsl:if don't need to be a single literal result element as in my example, they can be any instructions.